# Why is Visual Studio 2022 suggesting IDE0251 to make my method readonly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I've cloned a repository and was toying with it.  I was looking at the Error List generated by Visual Studio, and one of the suggestions was this:

[image: Read-only Method?]

I'm scratching my head trying to understand why this is being suggested.

Comment: "This rule flags members of non-`readonly` structs that aren't marked `readonly` that could be marked as `readonly`." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0251 Not sure how it applies to this though!

Comment: What does "Show potential fixes" reveal?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#readonly-instance-members  _You can also apply the `readonly` modifier to methods that override methods declared in System.Object_ I assume this is a struct?

Comment: @TimothyG. I see. Thanks. And indeed it is a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that it is overriding `Equals` (which is apart of `System.Object`), you can apply a `readonly` modifier to it according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#readonly-instance-members):

> You can also apply the `readonly` modifier to methods that override methods declared in System.Object